# Why does my Datadog APM Query show data in the APM section, but not for the dashboards section?

Tags: datadog, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing, datadog-dashboard, open-telemetry-collector

I am running a Datadog APM query, and I am able to see my traces in the APM section. However, when I try the same query parameters (env and service) in the query definition of the dashboards section, I am getting no data.

I have a java application that is instrumented using OpenTelemetry, and I have a local OTel collector setup on port 4317, and I'm using a Datadog agent with DD_OTLP_CONFIG_RECEIVER_PROTOCOLS_GRPC_ENDPOINT set to point to port 4317. Both the OTel collector and the datadog agent are setup as docker containers.

I am able to see the data in the APM section, just not in the dashboard section.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn’t a direct method to accomplish this through user control. However, it’s possible to do so by modifying the graph data via JSON. Here’s how you can do it:

Press the edit button on your graph.

Go to the ***Graph your data*** section and select the ***Json*** tab.

Replace ‘tace-search’ with ‘*’ in the indexes.

[tace-search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4FHL.png)

Hit the save button.

Please note that if you make any modifications on the dashboard using the Edit option, you’ll need to repeat these steps.